# Watching page (month) change

Tags: vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm using the Day Grid Month, how can I attach an event listener to trigger whenever I change the current page (month)? I tried using a watcher but didn't work

```
  mounted () {
    const api = this.$refs.fullCalendar.getApi()
    this.$watch(
      () => api.currentData.dateProfile.currentRange.start,
      newValue => console.log(newValue),
      { deep: true }
    )
  }
```

Comment: For what purpose? If you want to load more events when the date changes, use on of the event feed techniques shown in the documentation (I.e. events as JSON as or events as Function) - then fullcalendar will automatically ask your data source for more events whenever it needs them

Comment: `$watch` only detects changes on reactive objects (e.g: objects returned by the `data` function, or `Vue.observable()`). It is important to understand Vue makes them reactive. Javascript objects, by default, are not reactive. You need use the hooks (events) provided by the plugin.

Comment: Thanks, I first tried to get by filtering my events by month/year, after learning about events as function I changed my API to filter by start and end date and it worked